# How do you add a DisplayListener in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I'm adding a camera page using the CameraX library in Jetpack Compose. I want to support both landscape and portrait mode for image capturing. I read the android tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/orientation-rotation#displayListener) and decided that I needed to add a DisplayManager.DisplayListener to listen for when the device orientation changes and update my imageCapture.targetRotation. Here's the code I use to make my camera view.

```
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
var previewUseCase by remember { mutableStateOf<UseCase>(Preview.Builder().build()) }
val imageCaptureUseCase by remember {
    mutableStateOf(
        ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
            .build()
    )
}
Box {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            val previewView = PreviewView(context).apply {
                this.scaleType = scaleType
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
            }

            previewUseCase = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                }

            previewView
        }
    )
    CapturePictureButton(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
        onClick = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                onImageFile(imageCaptureUseCase.takePicture(context.executor))
            }
        }
    )
}
LaunchedEffect(previewUseCase) {
    val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
    try {
        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them.
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, previewUseCase, imageCaptureUseCase
        )
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Log.e("CameraCapture", "Failed to bind camera use cases", ex)
    }
}
// Maybe a DisposableEffect or LaunchedEffect here?
```

I'm new to Jetpack Compose, but I think I need a DisposableEffect or Launched effect at the bottom that adds an observer that listens for changes in the display.